# Puppeteer: How to listen to object events

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, headless, puppeteer

Is it possible to listen to events dispatched by in-page objects? Let's say I have this code in the page I go to:

```
var event = new CustomEvent('status', { detail: 'ok' });
window.addEventListener('status', function(e) {
  console.log('status: ', e.detail);
});
setInterval(window.dispatchEvent, 1000, event);
```

I'd like to be able to listen to events dispatched by the window object (or any other JS object for that matter). How can I do this in Puppeteer?

Comment: There's an example of listening for a custom event in the repo: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/examples/custom-event.js

Comment: Thank you! that's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 25):

First, you have to expose a function that can be called from within the page. Second, you listen for the event and call the exposed function and pass on the event data.

```js
// Expose a handler to the page
await page.exposeFunction('onCustomEvent', ({ type, detail }) => {
    console.log(`Event fired: ${type}, detail: ${detail}`);
});

// listen for events of type 'status' and
// pass 'type' and 'detail' attributes to our exposed function
await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
    window.addEventListener('status', ({ type, detail }) => {
        window.onCustomEvent({ type, detail });
    });
});

await page.goto(/* ... */);
```

If there is an event `status` fired in the page now (like the code you have given), you would see it being logged in the console of your Node.js application.

As posted in the comments, a more complex example can be found in the [puppeteer examples](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/examples/custom-event.js).

Comment: Hi there. Following the simple approach explained in here, I call in my static html, at the end of my lengthy page render: var event = new Event("sceneReady"); window.dispatchEvent(event); but the event listener is never reached at the NodeJS code counterpart.

Comment: To listen to `event`s fired on `document` use `document.addEventListener()` instead of `window.addEventListener()` in the `page.evaluateOnNewDocument()` method.

Answer (score 8):

A simpler method `await waitForEvent('event-name', 10)`

```js
/**
 * Wait for the browser to fire an event (including custom events)
 * @param {string} eventName - Event name
 * @param {integer} seconds - number of seconds to wait.
 * @returns {Promise} resolves when event fires or timeout is reached
 */
async function waitForEvent(eventName, seconds) {

    seconds = seconds || 30;

    // use race to implement a timeout
    return Promise.race([

        // add event listener and wait for event to fire before returning
        page.evaluate(function(eventName) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                document.addEventListener(eventName, function(e) {
                    resolve(); // resolves when the event fires
                });
            });
        }, eventName),

        // if the event does not fire within n seconds, exit
        page.waitForTimeout(seconds * 1000)
    ]);
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/orca-scan/puppeteer-cucumber-js/blob/main/runtime/helpers.js#L71)

Comment: Best answer IMO

Comment: How do you use it? I'm doing: ```
  await page.goto('http://localhost:1234');
  await waitForEvent('myCustomEvent');
```
I can add a custom event handler and see my event is definitely getting fired, but this promise never resolves.

Comment: Nevermind, I was using `window.dispatchEvent` to fire my event and not `document.dispatchEvent`

Comment: One glitch I ran into that was non-obvious to me: It looks like `Promise.race` doesn't  cancel the `waitForTimeout` promise. This means that if you have a 30 second timeout in `waitForEvent` then your puppeteer script will run for at least 30 seconds while it waits for the timeout promise to resolve even if the event fired. I didn't see an obvious/simple way to fix this so I've just stopped using the timeout in my script.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to actually await the custom event, you can do it this way.

```
const page = await browser.newPage();

/**
  * Attach an event listener to page to capture a custom event on page load/navigation.
  * @param {string} type Event name.
  * @return {!Promise}
  */
function addListener(type) {
  return page.evaluateOnNewDocument(type => {
    // here we are in the browser context
    document.addEventListener(type, e => {
      window.onCustomEvent({ type, detail: e.detail });
    });
  }, type);
}

const evt = await new Promise(async resolve => {
  // Define a window.onCustomEvent function on the page.
  await page.exposeFunction('onCustomEvent', e => {
    // here we are in the node context
    resolve(e); // resolve the outer Promise here so we can await it outside
  });
  await addListener('status'); // setup listener for "status" custom event on page load
  await page.goto('http://example.com');  // N.B! Do not use { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' } as that may cause a race condition
});

console.log(`${evt.type} fired`, evt.detail || '');
```

Built upon the example at https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/examples/custom-event.js